# Stray start tag head, Element style not allowed as child of element body in this context. (Suppressing further errors from this subtree.)

Tags: php, html, css, validation

These validation errors came up after I was correcting my code (putting link to Icon inside head). I believe the problem is combined in my header.php and home.php from the looks of it and from me trying to solve it. The validator also says my `<doctype! html>` is stray for some reason.

Header.php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/stylesheet.css" title="stylesheet">

<link rel="shortcut icon" property='icon' href="img/favicon.ico">

<?php if(isset($pageStyle)) : ?> 
<style type="text/css">
<?php echo $pageStyle; ?>
</style>
<?php endif; ?>
</head>
```

Home.php code:

```
<?php 
include("incl/config.php"); 
$title = "Hem";
$pageId = "hem";
$pageStyle = null;
?>

<?php include("incl/header.php"); ?>

<head>
<style>
html {
    background: url("img/church.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size:cover;

}
</style>
</head>
```

As you can see neither the `<head>` or doctype seems to be stray. The `<style>` is inside `<head>` as you can see as well, and not inside `<body>`. The reason `<style>` with background is set in home.php and not in my stylesheet is because I have different images as background for each page on my site. 
Is it possibly a structure error in this code?

Comment: There should only be one `head` block.

Comment: Please re-read your question - it looks like something has been stripped out because there are several places where words are missing from your text. EDIT:  I fixed it in an edit - that needs to pass the review queue

Comment: Thanks guys. 

Jon Stirling: Fixed it. Now the stray start tag head error disappeared from the validator. The element style not allowed in body error is still the same though.

Jen R: You're right, I'll edit it.

Answer (score 0):

Its best if you are going to open the `<head>` in an include file to not close it in that include file. Then you have the option to add to your `<head>`. Then you close it in the main code.

Try this instead

Header.php code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="sv">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title><?php echo $title; ?></title>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="style/stylesheet.css" title="stylesheet">

<link rel="shortcut icon" property='icon' href="img/favicon.ico">

<?php if(isset($pageStyle)) : ?> 
<style type="text/css">
<?php echo $pageStyle; ?>
</style>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Home.php code:

```
<?php 
include("incl/config.php"); 
$title = "Hem";
$pageId = "hem";
$pageStyle = null;
?>

<?php include("incl/header.php"); ?>

<style>
html {
    background: url("img/church.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
    background-size:cover;

}
</style>
</head>
```

Comment: Thanks. I was not aware of this. I did as you said and now the stray start tag head error disappeared. The element style not allowed as Child element of body is still there though.